# Get CPU Usage of Specific Program Command Line Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, cpu-usage, monitoring, process-explorer

Process explorer can show me the CPU % usage of a particular program:

[image]

I would like to obtain this number through command line to automatically sample the percentage utilization of a process. It has to be via command line so this can be automated, as I have another program I'm working on that needs this information updated every few seconds to do some calculations.

How can I obtain this number through command line on Windows 10, given the PID and/or process name?

Comment: Which “command line”? Command Prompt or PowerShell? PowerShell will make this much easier.

Comment: @DanielB, Powershell is fine